# Exception when Windows Service(WCF) is starting on SOME computers?

Tags: .net, windows, wcf, security, windows-services

I have a WCF service using net.tcp communication to a fat winforms client. The installation of the windows service is made with a install.bat that looks like this :

```
@ECHO OFF

REM The following directory is for .NET 4.0
set DOTNETFX2=%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
set PATH=%PATH%;%DOTNETFX2%

echo Installing IEPPAMS Win Service...
echo ---------------------------------------------------
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil "%~dp0MyApp.WindowsService.exe"
echo ---------------------------------------------------
pause
echo Done.
```

On some computers I need to save this bat as ASKI and also get full rights on the .NET Framework 4.0 folder but other then that the service is usually installed and started without problems.

But then on some computers I will get the following message when trying to start the service :

> The MyApp service on MyComputer started and then stopped. Some
>   services stop automatically if they are not in use by other service or
>   program.

Windows Event log states this exception :

> Service cannot be started.
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[MyApp.DataContracts.FaultContracts.Generellt.GeneralFault]:
>   (Fault Detail is equal to
>   MyApp.DataContracts.FaultContracts.Generellt.GeneralFault).

When starting the service 3 WCF service will start and all of them have there own baseadress and port number.

I suspect that this have something to do with a extra secured environment? But I don't know how to solve it.

This have been tested on Windows 2003 and 2008 R2

Comment: enable tracing (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx) in app.confing to get nice log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that there was error in data from database and the exception handling did not work at startup.

Answer (score 0):

A `FaultException` is thrown while you're calling the service. If you post the full exception, I believe we'll see that.

Such an exception is raised by WCF when it receives a SOAP Fault message from the service. It appears that the service is throwing a `FaultException<MyApp.DataContracts.FaultContracts.Generellt.GeneralFault>`.

You should ask the service why it's doing that. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Might be a rights issue, which would explain the variability. Setting up a listener on a port requires "admin" rights over the host server. You can run the command below (from the CMD prompt) to ensure that the web service doesn't have any rights problems when starting:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8000/MyUri user=\everyone listen=yes
```

Obviously, this is only for development and testing, not production.

There's an explanation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc307223(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: -1: sorry, but how would such a rights issue cause a `FaultException` to be thrown?